# Python typing: Handling Type[T] -> T method in generic class with inheritance where T is generic itself

Tags: python, python-3.x, generics, type-hinting, python-typing

I'm trying to implement abstract generic class and refine generic method parameters / return value in subclasses, and I get a weird type error hint from MyPY.

I would really appreciate if someone could explain me whether I'm wrong.

I have a simple type hierarchy for type bound:

```python
class BaseCredentials(ABC):
   pass

class StringCredentials(BaseCredentials):
   pass

class UserPassCredentials(BaseCredentials):
   pass

CredsType = TypeVar("CredsType", bound=BaseCredentials)

CredsTypeCoV = TypeVar(
    "CredsTypeCoV",
    bound=BaseCredentials,
    covariant=True
)
```

and generic class hierarchy bound to this type:

```python
class RawCredentialsEntity(ABC, Generic[CredsTypeCoV]):
    @abstractmethod
    def parse(
        self, clazz: Optional[Type[BaseCredentials]] = None
    ) -> CredsTypeCoV:
        raise NotImplementedError("Must be implemented!")

class EnvCredentialsEntity(
    RawCredentialsEntity[CredsTypeCoV], Generic[CredsTypeCoV],
):
    some_var_common_for_subtype: Any

class TextEnvCredentialsEntity(
    EnvCredentialsEntity[StringCredentials]
):
    def parse(
        self, clazz: Optional[Type[BaseCredentials]] = None
    ) -> StringCredentials:
        # logic
        return StringCredentials("some id", "some value")

class UserPassEnvCredentialsEntity(
    EnvCredentialsEntity[UserPassCredentials]
):
    def parse(
        self, clazz: Optional[Type[BaseCredentials]] = None
    ) -> UserPassCredentials:
        # logic
        return UserPassCredentials("id", "user", "password")

RawEntityType = TypeVar(
    "RawEntityType", bound=RawCredentialsEntity[BaseCredentials],
)
```

Motivation of such hierarchy: `BaseCredentials` and `RawCredentialsEntity` are interface-like base types, and their extra subtypes are subject to be implemented in plugin style.

`clazz` parameter is needed only for business logic purposes, it may be any of subtypes of `BaseCredentials` irrespectively to subtype generic type.

Here is how this hierarchy is going to be used:

```python
class BaseCredentialsSource(ABC, Generic[RawEntityType]):
    @abstractmethod
    def load_all(self) -> List[RawEntityType]:
        raise NotImplementedError("Must be implemented!")

    @abstractmethod
    def load(
        self, credentials_id: str,
        clazz: Type[RawEntityType]
    ) -> RawEntityType:
        raise NotImplementedError("Must be implemented!")

class EnvCredentialsSource(
    BaseCredentialsSource[EnvCredentialsEntity[BaseCredentials]]
):
    def load_all(self) -> List[EnvCredentialsEntity[BaseCredentials]]:
        return []

    def load(
        self, credentials_id: str,
        clazz: Type[EnvCredentialsEntity[CredsTypeCoV]]
    ) -> EnvCredentialsEntity[CredsTypeCoV]:
        pass
```

The following usage sample fails validation:

```python
service = EnvCredentialsSource()
all_ent: List[EnvCredentialsEntity[BaseCredentials]] = service.load_all() # passes as expected
ent1: UserPassEnvCredentialsEntity = service.load("test_id", TextEnvCredentialsEntity) # expected to fail, I want strict Type[T] -> T where T is bounded to EnvCredentialsEntity
ent2: UserPassEnvCredentialsEntity = service.load("test_id", UserPassEnvCredentialsEntity) # fails, I wonder why
```

Fail error is: `Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "EnvCredentialsEntity[UserPassCredentials]", variable has type "UserPassEnvCredentialsEntity")`

Answer (score 0):

Answer is very simple - I expect return containers to be covariant, whereas List is not, because it's mutable. It's required to use Sequence and Mapping in such cases.

I rewrote code to make pypy happy this way:

```python
class RawCredentialsEntity(ABC, Generic[CredsTypeCoV]):
    @abstractmethod
    def parse(
        self, clazz: Optional[Type[CredsTypeCoV]] = None
    ) -> CredsTypeCoV:
        raise NotImplementedError("Must be implemented!")

class EnvCredentialsEntity(
    RawCredentialsEntity[CredsTypeCoV], Generic[CredsTypeCoV],
):
    pass

class BaseCredentialsSource(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def load_all(self) -> Sequence[
        RawCredentialsEntity[CredsType]
    ]:
        raise NotImplementedError("Must be implemented!")

    @abstractmethod
    def load(
        self, credentials_id: str,
        clazz: Type[RawEntityType]
    ) -> RawEntityType:
        raise NotImplementedError("Must be implemented!")


class TextEnvCredentialsEntity(
    EnvCredentialsEntity[StringCredentials]
):
    def parse(
        self, clazz: Optional[Type[BaseCredentials]] = None
    ) -> StringCredentials:
        ...
        return StringCredentials(credentials_id, value)

class EnvCredentialsSource(BaseCredentialsSource):
    def load_all(
        self
    ) -> Sequence[EnvCredentialsEntity[CredsType]]:
        return []

    def load(
        self, credentials_id: str,
        clazz: Type[RawEntityType]
    ) -> RawEntityType:
        pass
```